# Marginsize in Latex resume displays dimensions

Tags: latex, margins

I'm using Latex to write my resume, however the default margins for the resume doc type are too wide. The best way to correct this is using the anysize package then setting the margin size, however doing so causes the "=.5=.75" to display before my title in the pdf. Here is the header code

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[margin]{res}
% \usepackage[margin=0.75in,bottom=.5in,top=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}%%%%
\usepackage{anysize}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.8in} % set width of text portion

\begin{document}

\marginsize{.5}{.5}{.75}{.75}

% Center the name over the entire width of resume:
\centerline{\large\bf John Doe}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the lengths using some unit of measure. For example:

```
\marginsize{.5in}{.5in}{.75in}{.75in}
```

However, as mentioned in the [`anysize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/anysize) [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/anysize/README)

> This package is obsolete. Use the package `typearea` to define your
>   margins typographically correct. Use the package `geometry` or `vmargin`
>   for everything else.

My suggestions would be to stick to [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package for setting your document layout. Also, not to use [`resume`](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) for setting a resumé. There's [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) as an alternative, or you could do just as well in the default `article` class.